# Invalid Expression ERROR 000358: Select by Attribute

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I'm attempting to select a certain point in a feature layer so I can perform buffer analysis on it. The code seems fine, but I am getting an invalid expression error:

> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute
>       raise e
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
>   Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
where = """ Location = 'C' """
print where
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Q:\Admin\F2F_Scripts\Tools\Template\Intermediate\DATA\Temp.gdb\PADPOINTS", "POINTS")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("POINTS","NEW_SELECTION", where)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("POINTS", "Q:\Admin\F2F_Scripts\Tools\Template\Intermediate\DATA\Temp.gdb\Buff", "100 Feet")
arcpy.Delete_management("POINTS")
del where
```

Comment: Try copy/pasting your expression into a `select by attribute` or a definition query in ArcMap and see if it works for you.

Comment: I've already tried and it worked fine. I'm unsure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking at ESRI's page http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/specifying-a-query.htm (Written for Pro, but most of the tools and syntax listed work in Desktop, especially the Add Field Delimiters function.) I hate using SQL queries in ArcPy and avoid it wherever I can, but from the look of their sample code, your query should read closer to `"Location" = 'C'`.

Check also how your field *name* is formatted. Is "Location" your field name or your field alias? Go into your feature class's Attribute Table and check that field's properties to figure out whether it's a name or an alias. Given the presence of lowercase letters, I bet that it's an alias, and your field name is different.

Comment: You're right, the name of the feature class is different. my script is working now. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I found I need to right-click on the layer and select Design > Fields to see the actual field names when a table is joined.