# Selecting a feature by field value

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, python-3

I have a layer called 'Colorado' that has an attribute 'FIPS_CODE'. The values are numbers as a string. I am trying to use `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` inside my Python script to select the features that have code '13245', but I keep getting an error:

> Invalid expression Failed to execute

The problem is essentially the `where_clause` or SQL Expression. What am I doing wrong here?

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Colorado','NEW_SELECTION','"FIPS_CODE" = "13245"')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Expression ERROR 000358: Select by Attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183764/invalid-expression-error-000358-select-by-attribute)

Comment: Is FIPS_CODE numeric or text?  The double-quotes are incorrect either way, but should be single-quotes if text, and not present if numeric.

Comment: It's a string, so text even though it is a number. Ex: '13245', '13015', etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

and three double quotes:

```
sql = """{0} = '13245'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('Colorado','FIPS_CODE'))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='Colorado', where_clause=sql)
```

'Colorado' needs to be a layer, for example created with MakeFeatureLayer.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The syntax was just a little off. Here is the correct application: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Georgia", "NEW_SELECTION", "FIPS_CODE = '13245'")`

Comment: @gwydion93 nice!. But if you use addfielddelimiters you will never have this problem. Some other time the field name will have to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Hypothetically, in Python3.6, say I had a variable `id = '13245'` and I wanted to insert that variable into my code. How would I do that? `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Georgia", "NEW_SELECTION", "FIPS_CODE = " + id)`?

Comment: (id is a function so dont name it id). Use format: `"""FIPS_CODE = '{0}'""".format(idnumber)`